# Unable to make element the same height on window resize using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted to match the height of my sidebar to my video player element so basically I have this html structure https://codepen.io/leonardpbdigital/pen/gOrmmro

For some reason I'm not able to figure out why is that I'm getting different values of the height of both elements. Please see this quick video https://share.getcloudapp.com/KourYlWq

I don't want to add an `overflow:hidden` to my sidebar because I have buttons outside the box that needs to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because of `transition` property is css. You need to remove transition over the main element (which you are using to measure height).

Alternatively you need to recalculate height of the sidebar after 0.5s of the last `resize` event (when transition is over):

```
var resizeTimeout = null;
$(window).resize(() => {
    matchHeight();
    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(matchHeight, 500);
});
```